# Invoking factory when including custom class in controller in dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I've got a web service (dotnet core 1.1).

I've created a class which I want to have show up via dependency injection in my controller's constructor.  This works out...

Startup.cs has something like this...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... stuff ...
    services.AddSingleton<IMyClassFactory, MyClassFactory>();
}
```

And MyController.cs has something like this:

```
public MyController(IConfigurationRoot config, ILogger<MyController> logger, IMyClassFactory mcf)
{
    // ... stuff ...

    // Here I can grab "mcf" and grab an instance.  Make a call like this:
    // _myclass = mcf.GetMyClass(this.GetType().Name) 
}
```

Issue is, I would like to have the behavior be more like that of ILogger.  That is, I don't add an ILogger to a service collection in Startup.cs, but somehow the ILoggerFactory gives my controller the logger it wants.

What am I missing?  Please forgive, I'm new to dotnet.

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(FooHelper<>));
```

Where:

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : class
{
  string Process(T value);
}

public class FooHelper<T> : IFoo<T> where T : class
{
  public string Process(T value)
  {
    return "DepController";
  }
}
```

Will let you use:

```
public FooController(IFoo<FooController> helper)
```

This is a somewhat obscure use case, and I've seldom seen it used. Notice you can't use `services.AddSingleton(typeof(IFoo<>), (ctx) => { ... })` to specify how exactly the implementation is constructed, as there's no way to access the T in this case, and you'll just get:

> System.ArgumentException: Open generic service type 'LearnWebApi.Core.IFoo`1[T]' requires registering an open generic implementation type.

If you want custom behaviour I believe your bet option is to inject a custom factory into the controller and use something like:

```
IFoo<Thing> _helper;

...

public FooController(FooFactory factory) {
  _helper = factory.Resolve<Thing>();
}
```